# Is this method head correct? (Bounded type variables in Java)

Tags: java, variables, generics, types, bounded-types

In this [The Grey Blog](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/bounded-type-variables.html) tutorial about Java Generics, the author tries to show how to write a method head that uses Generics in such a way as to check whether a parent class of the object that method takes as an argument implements a certain interface.

The following classes are involved:

```
public interface Juicy<T> {
    Juice<T> squeeze();
}

    class Orange extends Fruit implements Juicy<Orange>;
    class RedOrange extends Orange;
```

Now we want to "squeeze" a `List` of red oranges using the squeeze method that only the class `Orange` implements:

```
<T extends Juicy<? super T>> List<Juice<? super T>> squeezeSuperExtends(List<? extends T> fruits);
```

At the beginning `<T extends Juicy<? super T>>` declares that T must either directly implement the interface `Juicy` or be subclass of a class that implements `Juicy` (I hope I am right so far?)

But then, when the method declares its argument types `(List<? extends T> fruits)` it again declares that the List can contain objects ob T or of any of Ts subclasses.

Wouldn't it be enough to write either the first part:

```
<T extends Juicy<T>> List<Juice<? super T>> squeezeSuperExtends2(List<? extends T> fruits)
```

or the last part:

```
<T extends Juicy<? super T>> List<Juice<? super T>> squeezeSuperExtends3(List<T> fruits)
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to only squeeze a list of blood oranges, why not just make a list of blood oranges? Don't use generics there

Comment: But, if a `RedOrange` *is-a* `Orange` and you want to squeeze a `RedOrange` like an `Orange`, what's stopping you?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils nothing is stopping me, I just wonder if the method head could be simplified?

Comment: Is the goal just to return Juice objects whose generic type coresponds to that of the method argument?  I feel like `<T> List<Juice<T>> squeezeAll(List<? extends Juicy<T>> fruits)` would accomplish that.